# How to create the following HTML dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create the following HTML dynmaically

```
<p id="address">Name
    <br> City,
    <br> address,
    <br> +9023562567, +91 7023344335
    <br>
    <strong>Potential (MT) :</strong> 4000
</p>
```

I was trying it this way

```
var html= '';

var name = 'Mark' ;
var city = 'California'
var address = 'Losangles';
var phone1 = '9023562567' ;
var phone2 = '7023344335' ;
var mt= 'Potential (MT)' ;
var mtvalue = '4000' ;

 html += '+name+'<br>\n\
                        '+city+',<br>\n\
                        '+address+',<br>\n\
                        +'+phone1+', +'+phone2+'<br>\n\
                        <strong>'+mt+' :</strong> +mtvalue+</p>\n\


 $("#id").html(html);
```

But i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

could you please let me know how to resole this

please excuse if this is a dumb question .

http://jsfiddle.net/r69bou3n/6/

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you trying to create an address box like you would see on a "Contact Us" page?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/r69bou3n/9/

Comment: @MichaelWiggins , i just want to create a HTML of it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot split a string between lines using `\`

```
html += name + '<br>' + city + ',<br>' + address + ',<br>+' + phone1 + ', +' + phone2 + '<br><strong>' + mt + ' :</strong> +mtvalue+</p>';
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/r69bou3n/10/)

**EDIT**

You are using wrong selector to add `html`:

```
$('#address').html(html);
//  ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st)**
your **id is not correct** use `#address`

```
$("#address").html(html);
```

**2nd)**
Your concatenated html should be:

```
 html += name+'<br>\n\'+
 city+',<br>\n\'
                        address+',<br>\n\+'
                        +phone1+', +'
                        +phone2+'<br>\n\<strong>'
                        +mt+' :</strong> +mtvalue+</p>\n\';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` string is wrong. Try with this:

```
var html= '';
var name = 'Mark' ;
var city = 'California'
var address = 'Losangles';
var phone1 = '9023562567' ;
var phone2 = '7023344335' ;
var mt= 'Potential (MT)' ;
var mtvalue = '4000' ;
html += name+'<br>'+city+',<br>'+address+',<br>'+phone1+', '+phone2+'<br><strong>'+mt+' :</strong> '+mtvalue+'</p>';

$("#address").html(html);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/r69bou3n/16/

Answer (score 0):

you have an error here:

```
                <strong>'+mt+' :</strong> +mtvalue+</p>\n\
```

change it to:

```
                <strong>'+mt+' :</strong> '+mtvalue+'</p>';
```

also you should change

```
html += '+name+'<br>\n\
```

with

```
html += '<p>'+name+'<br>
```

and remove all the \n\ from your string

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there is no need of `\n` with `<br>`:

```
var html= '';

var name = 'Mark' ;
var city = 'California'
var address = 'Losangles';
var phone1 = '9023562567' ;
var phone2 = '7023344335' ;
var mt= 'Potential (MT)' ;
var mtvalue = '4000' ;

 html += name+'<br>'+city+',<br>'+address+',<br>+'+phone1+', +'+phone2+'<br><strong>'+mt+' :</strong>' +mtvalue+'</p>';


 $("#address").html(html);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r69bou3n/15/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work , Tested

```
var name = 'Mark' ;
var city = 'California'
var address = 'Losangles';
var phone1 = '9023562567' ;
var phone2 = '7023344335' ;
var mt= 'Potential (MT)' ;
var mtvalue = '4000' ;

 var html = name+"<br>"+
            city+",<br>"+
             address+",<br>"+
             phone1+", "+phone2+"<br>"+
             "<strong>"+mt+" :</strong> "+mtvalue+"</p>";


 $("#id").html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var html= '';

    var name = 'Mark' ;
    var city = 'California'
    var address = 'Losangles';
    var phone1 = '9023562567' ;
    var phone2 = '7023344335' ;
    var mt= 'Potential (MT)' ;
    var mtvalue = '4000' ;

    html += name+'<br>\n\
                    '+city+',<br>\n\
                    '+address+',<br>\n\
                    +'+phone1+', +'+phone2+'<br>\n\
                    <strong>'+mt+' :</strong>' +mtvalue+'</p>\n\
    ';


     $("#address").html(html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r69bou3n/19/